# SQL Select Case Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.

Tags: sql, sql-server

Folks, I've read the fixes for this issue but I have a variation that I can't solve.

Firstly the following syntax throws the error

```
 Case
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161165 then REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), cast([dCreatedUTC] as datetime), 106), ' ', '-')
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161166 then 'Administrator'
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161167 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161168 then AssetID
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161169 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161170 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161172 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161173 then ''
    else CAST(#TFs.lTFID as varchar(20))
  End 'Value'
```

If I comment out all but one of the "when" lines as below it works.

```
 Case
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161165 then REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), cast([dCreatedUTC] as datetime), 106), ' ', '-')
/*  when #TFs.lTFID = 1161166 then 'Administrator'
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161167 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161168 then AssetID
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161169 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161170 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161172 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161173 then ''*/
    else CAST(#TFs.lTFID as varchar(20))
  End 'Value'
```

Any thoughts about how I can format this query so that all "cases" work?

Comment: What is the datatype of your `AssetID` column in your table??

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: If your `AssetID` is a *numerical* datatype (`int`, `decimal` etc.), you would need to do a `CAST(AssetID AS VARCHAR(n))` on it, too (like for your `dCreatedUTC` column) so that every `WHEN` clause returns the same datatype to the `CASE` expression

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the error message, the result of the `CASE` expressions gets converted to `INT`. Also of the return value of your `WHEN`s is known to be `VARCHAR`, except for `AssetID`, so I assume this must be an `INT` value.

The error happens because when using a `CASE` expression, all return values must be of the same data type. In case they have different data types, all values are converted to the type with a higher [**data type precedence**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

And since `INT` has a higher precedence than `VARCHAR`, the results are converted to `INT` which caused the error. To fix this, you have to convert `AssetID` to `VARCHAR(n)` also

```
Case
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161165 then REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), cast([dCreatedUTC] as datetime), 106), ' ', '-')
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161166 then 'Administrator'
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161167 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161168 then CAST(AssetID AS VARCHAR(20))
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161169 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161170 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161172 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161173 then ''
    else CAST(#TFs.lTFID as varchar(20))
End 'Value'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try and cast the AssetID to a varchar in the case statement.

```
Case
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161165 then REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), cast([dCreatedUTC] as datetime), 106), ' ', '-')
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161166 then 'Administrator'
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161167 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161168 then CAST(AssetID AS VARCHAR(20))
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161169 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161170 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161172 then ''
    when #TFs.lTFID = 1161173 then ''
    else CAST(#TFs.lTFID as varchar(20))
  End 'Value'
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. For Amit Sukralia I should have been clearer with my question. the error message is in the subject "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int." However I should have been more explicit. The original error was "Conversion failed when converting the varchar '2016-03-31' value to data type int. This is what kept throwing me as I didn't focus on the AssetID as its already an int and I didn't believe it need to be Cast. In addition Felix Pamittan's answer it technically correct but until I saw the fault in my own code I didn't truly understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Case #TFs.lTFID
 When 1161165 then REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), cast([dCreatedUTC] as datetime), 106), ' ', '-')
 When 1161166 then 'Administrator'
 .
 .
 .
 Else CAST(#TFs.lTFID as varchar(20)) END
```

Answer (score -3):

Put your `CAST` outside the the `CASE` as follows:

```
     CAST(
             Case
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161165 then REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), cast([dCreatedUTC] as datetime), 106), ' ', '-')
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161166 then 'Administrator'
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161167 then ''
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161168 then AssetID
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161169 then ''
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161170 then ''
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161172 then ''
                when #TFs.lTFID = 1161173 then ''
                else #TFs.lTFID
              End 
         as varchar(20)) 'Value'
```

Comment: If AssetID is an Integer then this will still return the same error.